# Ajax not loading by jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a bit new and trying to load text in a local text file using ajax through "XAMPP" requests, by jquery. I am doing everything correct, but still ajax data not loading from text-file to my div. Can anyone tell me why, as I am doing everything right. Here, goes snippet:

**Jquery**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#but1").click(function() {
            $("#div1").load("ajaxfile.txt");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
     margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
div{
    background:yellow;
    padding:30px;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin:20px;
}
```

**Html**

```
<button id=but1>One</button>
<div id=div1> 
   This is div:
</div>
```

I can do it with javaScript, but, I want to do it with jQuery and by loading data from external txt file only. Also, if you may tell me, what changes will I make to load it with JSON format, and XML file format. Thank you dear!

@spirulence: Dear, for your request, I am posting the file which worked by 'javascript xmlhttp' rather than the 'jquery' method.

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxfile.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the development console of your browser?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 2 errors while watching at console: 
1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) ------- http://localhost/ajax/jquery.js

2) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  ------- example13.html:8

Comment: But, if my XAMPP is showing 404 error, then I cannot understand, how then it can open the webpage, as I am not using .html browser to open but opening it by going through "localhost/ajax/index13.html". Thanks for help!

Comment: Do your Apache logs show the 404 error? Can you post your main Apache config and any .htaccess files in use?

Comment: Well, thats a bit much, but I can tell you, when I am doing same with jquery xmlhttp method I can get access to my txtfile. The problem is only with jquery, so I dont think there is any problem in apache config or MIME type. It would be helpful if you could point out my mistake in the <code> I have written.

Comment: Jack, I don't currently see a problem with what you've written, which is why I'm looking elsewhere. Could you post the code that does work?

Comment: If you are getting error "$ is not defined"  this is because of jquery core file.  Check http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js is loaded on not. and also try $("#div1").load("[FULL_BASE_PATH]/ajaxfile.txt");

Comment: @php freqk. Yep, there was some problem in the loading of jquery file. I copied cdn and tried again. It worked! Thanks buddy!

Comment: @jack : then you can mark my comment as useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at downloading json then I recommend you to us:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {

  });
```

For different content types, you can use $.get() and specify  content types.

Also, make sure that the path is relative and attached to the same domain otherwise you will face CORS issues.

If you are getting 404 then you got to check that the file exists on server and your IIS Pool(whichever) user has rights to access the same.

Comment: I have placed the "ajaxfile.txt" in the same folder, i.e., htdocs/ajax/ajaxfile.txt where I have put my index13.html to get the ajax data through jquery, on XAMPP. Still not getting what got wrong ! ;(

Comment: @JackSparrow can you browse to the url through the browser? Make sure that the mime type registered.

Comment: I can use browser or traverse through using localhost. I can also load the file when using xmlhttp method of javascript. The only problem seems here is with the jquery!

Comment: try to put this code: $(function(){ debugger;
  $.get('',function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
});

and then open console, hit refresh. try to get change $.get('' with your path and see the response.

Comment: Thanks buddy. There was some problem in the jquery loading. I used the cdn from google, and this time it worked. Thanks for suggetions!